# ¿Cómo generar dos nuevas cadenas sin reemplazar las originales?

Tags: python

Tengo un problemón en mi código. Este programa genera dos listas nuevas a partir de otras dos. Desde la variable punto hasta donde termina la lista interna, cruza los dígitos de ambas listas. El problema está en que cuando quiero agregar esas nuevas listas a la lista grande, si las agrega pero también me reemplaza las listas que tomé originalmente por las nuevas, y eso es lo que no quiero que pase y no se por qué sucede eso.

```
pob = [[0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1], [1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1], [0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0], [0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1]]
punto = 5

print("Poblacion original:")
for x in range(0,len(pob)):
    print(f"Individuo {x}: {pob[x]}")

ind1 = pob[0]
ind2 = pob[2]

print()
print(f"Individuo seleccionado 1: {ind1}; Individuo seleccionado 2: {ind2}")
print()
print(f"Cruzar individuos a partir de la posicion: {punto}")
print()

for x in range(punto,len(ind1)):
    aux = ind1[x]
    ind1[x] = ind2[x]
    ind2[x] = aux

print(f"Nuevo individuo 1: {ind1}; Nuevo individuo 2: {ind2}")

pob.append(ind1)
pob.append(ind2)

print()
print("Poblacion nueva:")
for x in range(0,len(pob)):
    print(f"Individuo {x}: {pob[x]}")
```

Por ejemplo. El resultado que debo obtener es este:

```
Población nueva:
Individuo 0: [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
Individuo 1: [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
Individuo 2: [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
Individuo 3: [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
Individuo 4: [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
Individuo 5: [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
```

Pero obtengo esto en su lugar:

```
Población nueva:
Individuo 0: [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
Individuo 1: [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
Individuo 2: [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
Individuo 3: [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
Individuo 4: [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
Individuo 5: [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
```

Comment: el código es extenso. Por favor, dale a [edit] para mostrar solamente las partes relevantes y, además, proporcionar un [mcve]. De lo contrario, es complicado abordar toda la problemática de forma fácil.

Comment: puedes crear una copia con `from copy import copy` y luego ya solo haces la copia `nuevo=copy(viejo)` y podras trabajar con `nuevo` si afectar a `viejo`....

Comment: ¿Y cómo lo implemento en mi código? ¿Qué debo cambiar exactamente o cómo lo agrego?

Comment: Ya encontré cómo y si me sirvió. Era justo lo que fallaba, aunque no era como lo habías puesto, sino `nuevo=viejo.copy()`. Gracias @Bryro

Comment: @Bryro. Mejor publica una respuesta explicando la situación, para beneficio de todos.

Comment: puedes publicarla estoy desde el mobil es algo dificil hacerlo desde aqui :(

Comment: El detalle está en que cuando hago la igualación de la variable con la lista, ambos espacios ocupan el mismo lugar y por ende, lo que hacía en una, se hacía con la otra. En vez de hacer `ind1 = pob[0]` y `ind2 = pob[2]` se copia con el copy `ind1 = pob[0].copy()` y `ind2 = pob[2].copy()`

Answer (score 1):

En Python las variables se manejan por referencia. En castellano simple, una referencia es un alias, un nombre alternativo para un dato en memoria.

Cuando dices

```
lista1 = [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6]
lista2 = lista1
```

no estás generando una copia de `lista1`. Después de la asignación sigue existiendo una sola lista en memoria. Ambas variables, `lista1` y `lista2` apuntan a los mismo datos en memoria. Por tanto, cuando cambias algo en la lista, se ve refleja en ambas lista (porque ambas apuntan a lo mismo).

Esto se extiende a todas las operaciones sobre listas. Si agregas o eliminas un elemento, ambas variables se ven afectadas (porque ambas apuntan a lo mismo).

```
del lista2[0]
print(lista1)
print(lista2)
```

produce:

```
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6]
```

Si quieres **copiar** una lista, usa la función `copy`. Esta operación produce una lista totalmente nueva, separada de la original:

```
lista3 = lista1.copy()
lista3[0] = 555
print(lista1)
print(lista3)
```

produce:

```
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6]
[555, 2, 4, 5, 6]
```

En resumen:

- Cada elemento de la lista existe una sola vez en memoria.
- La lista completa (elementos + la estructura de la lista) existe sólo una vez en memoria.
- La lista puede tener múltiples nombres. Cada vez que asignas la lista a otra variable, estás dandole un nuevo nombre a la lista.

**`copy` no copia los elementos**

La función `copy` genera una nueva lista pobladas con los mismos elementos contenidos en el original. Por tanto, si modificas un elemento por una lista, la modificación se refleja también en la otra.

```
class nodo:
    def __init__(self, valor):
        self.valor = valor

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.valor)

lista1 = [nodo(0), nodo(1), nodo(2), nodo(3)]
lista2 = lista1.copy()
lista2[0].valor = 100 # Modificamos el elemento, no la lista.
lista2.append(nodo(5)) # Modificamos la lista.

print(lista1)
print(lista2)
```

produce

```
[100, 1, 2, 3]
[100, 1, 2, 3, 5]
```

Entonces, `lista1[0]` y `lista2[0]`, aunque son listas distintas, comparten el mismo objeto `nodo`. Si alteras el objeto `nodo`, ambas listas se verán afectadas.

**Respuesta en formato C**

`lista1` es un puntero a una lista. Cuando haces

```
lista2 = lista1
```

estas sólo copiando punteros.

Cuando dices

```
lista2 = lista1.copy()
```

primero creas una lista vacía y luego la llenas con los valores contenidos en `lista1`. Si los elemento de `lista1` son objetos, sólo copias sus punteros desde una lista a otra.