# Por que sucede esto con modificacion de sublistas en python?

Tags: python, lista, funciones

Tengo un error en mi programa que supe identificar, pero no solucionar ni por que ocurre.

Tendremos una función que al ingresar un numero nos generara una lista con n cant de elementos y dentro de cada sublista n cantidad de elementos `'-'`.

Por ejemplo, si en la función ingreso un 1

```
1 -> [['-']], 2-> [['-','-'],['-','-']] 3-> [['-','-','-'],['-','-','-'],['-','-','-']] ...
```

También tendremos una función que nos agrega una palabra colocando 2 posiciones iniciales para la primer letra y luego avanzar horizontalmente.

Por separado las funciones actúan correctamente pero al unirlas no.

Veamos

```
def creaTablero(numero):
    t = ["-"]*numero
    t = [t]*numero
    return t

def aggHorizontal(tablero,palabra,posv,posh):
    v = posv
    h = posh

    for letra in palabra:
        tablero[v][h] = letra
        h +=1
    return tablero

creaTablero(3) -> [['-','-','-'],['-','-','-'],['-','-','-']]

aggHorizontal([['-','-','-'],['-','-','-'],['-','-','-']],"ola",0,0) -> [['o','l','a'],['-','-','-'],['-','-','-']]

aggHorizontal(creaTablero(3),"ola",0,0) -> [['o','l','a'],['o','l','a'],['o','l','a']]
```

Al unir las dos funciones la función `aggHorizontal` ya no actúa correctamente.

Si alguien sabe a que se debe esto porrr favor necestio ayudaaa, muchas graciaas

Comment: Es el mismo caso que https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/425810/c%c3%b3mo-generar-dos-nuevas-cadenas-sin-reemplazar-las-originales/426161#426161

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bienvenido a StackOverflow BochaAle c:

**EXPLICACION**

Tu problema ocurre debido a algo que haces en la función `creaTablero`.
Si tienes noción de lo que es un objeto en programación, seguro me entenderás facilmente, pero si no, haré lo mejor posible para explicarme.

Imagina que tienes tres vasos de agua, vaso1, vaso2 y vaso3 respectivamente. Cada nombre hace referencia al un vaso diferente.

Teniendo en cuenta el ejemplo de arriba, podemos deducir lo que sucede en tu código.
Imagina que tienes una lista `[vaso1]`
Por lo tanto, podemos decir que esta cuenta resulta en:

```
[vaso1]*3 = [vaso1]+[vaso1]+[vaso1] = [vaso1, vaso1, vaso1]
```

Como puedes ver, la lista no contiene los nombres de vaso1, vaso2 y vaso3, sino una referencia a vaso1.
Lo que esperarias en una lista con los tres vasos es

```
[vaso1: medio lleno, vaso2:1/4 lleno, vaso3: vacio]
```

Pero como en la lista anterior haces referencia solo al vaso1, sale:

```
[vaso1: medio lleno, vaso1: medio lleno, vaso1: medio lleno]
```

Ahora observa que sucedería si llenamos el vaso1 por completo:

```
[vaso1: lleno, vaso1: lleno, vaso1: lleno]
```

Esto se debe a que cada item de tu lista realmente hace referencia al mismo vaso, y no a los otros.

**CONCLUSION**

Ahora cambia los vasos por sublistas y sabras que, realmente en esa multilicación no creas nuevas listas, si no que agregas siempre la misma.
Eso significa que si alteras una sola de las sublistas, alteras todas, por que todos tus items hacen referencia a la misma sublista o vaso.

---

**SOLUCION**

Para solucionar tu problema, se puede usar compresión de listas, donde cada vez que el bucle se ejecuta, creamos una nueva lista.

```
def creaTablero(numero):
    t = [["-"]*numero for _ in range(numero)]
    return t
```

O, (agregado gracias a Benito-B c:) puedes lograr lo mismo de esta forma:

```
def creaTablero(numero):
    t = []

    for _ in range(numero):
        t.append(["-"]*numero)
        
    return t
```

*Nota adicional*: El guion bajo que uso no tiene ningún significado especial en Python, es solo un convenio para decir que el valor obtenido no tiene importancia. Mas información sobre el guion bajo aqui: https://hackernoon.com/understanding-the-underscore-of-python-309d1a029edc

Comment: Más fácil que usando list comprehension, si es para clase, tal vez le interese hacerlo con `append` sin más :)

Comment: Si antes habia utilizado el append pero sucedia los mismo, ahora lo entendi todo muchas gracias :)