# Utilizar un diccionario como atributo de una clase

Tags: python

Aquí esta el código:

```
class Personal_Universitario:
    datos = {
        'id': None,
        'nombre': None,
        'email': None
    }

    def __init__(self, datos=None):
        self.datos['id'] = datos['id']
        self.datos['nombre'] = datos['nombre']
        self.datos['email'] = datos['email']

    def __str__(self):
        return '''
         Id: \t{}
         Nombre: {}
         Email: \t{}'''.format(self.datos['id'], self.datos['nombre'], self.datos['email'], end="")


class Oficina(Personal_Universitario):

    def __init__(self, datos, puesto):
        super().__init__(datos)
        self.datos['puesto'] = puesto

    def __str__(self):
        return super().__str__() + ''' 
      Puesto: {}'''.format(self.datos['puesto'])


class Profesor(Personal_Universitario):
    def __init__(self, datos, especializacion):
        super().__init__(datos)
        self.datos['especializacion'] = especializacion

    def __str__(self):
        return super().__str__() + '''
         Especialización: {}'''.format(self.datos['especializacion'])


class Alumno(Personal_Universitario):
    def __init__(self, datos, creditos):
        super().__init__(datos)
        self.datos['creditosAprobados'] = creditos

    def __str__(self):
        return super().__str__() + '''
         Creditos aprobados: {}'''.format(self.datos['creditosAprobados'])


# Es mi información guardada en un diccionario, de diferentes personas.

persona1 = {'id': '50624002J', 'nombre': 'Alberto Torres', 'email': 'atb94ingmec@gmail.com'}
persona2 = {'id': '26598457P', 'nombre': 'Elena Garcia', 'email': 'elen98pol@gmail.com'}
persona3 = {'id': '45632589M', 'nombre': 'Jose Perez', 'email': 'Jose_95Per@gmail.com'}

# Creamos diferentes objetos de las distintas clases.

oficinista = Oficina(persona3, 'Administrativo')
profe = Profesor(persona1, 'Matemáticas')
alumn = Alumno(persona2, 230)
# Imprimimos la información del personal por pantalla.
print(oficinista)
print(profe)
```

Aquí están los resultados que me salen:

> ```
> Id:   26598457P Nombre: Elena Garcia Email:   elen98pol@gmail.com 
> Puesto: Administrativo
>
> Id:   26598457P Nombre: Elena Garcia Email:   elen98pol@gmail.com
> Especialización: Matemáticas
>
> Id:   26598457P Nombre: Elena Garcia Email:   elen98pol@gmail.com
> Creditos aprobados: 230
> ```

Le he dado varias vueltas, y no entiendo porqué siempre imprime los datos generales del último objeto que se ha creado, los atributos específicos de cada clase si funciona bien.

Answer (score 1):

El problema viene precisamente de que has usado un atributo **de clase**.

Al hacer lo siguiente:

```
class Personal_Universitario:
    datos = {
        'id': None,
        'nombre': None,
        'email': None
    }
```

declaras que la clase `Personal_Universitario` tenga un atributo `Personal_Universitario.datos`. Cuando luego mediante herencia creas otras clases, éstas heredarán el atributo `.datos` de la clase `Personal_Universitario`.

Los objetos que instancies, en cambio **no tendrán ese atributo**. Cuando intentas acceder a `profe.datos`, por ejemplo, (o lo que es lo mismo, cuando pones `self.datos` siendo `self` es el `profe`) lo que hará Python será:

- Buscar el atributo `.datos` dentro del objeto `profe` (no lo encontrará)
- Buscar entonces ese atributo en su clase, es decir, buscar `Profesor.datos` (no lo encontrará)
- Seguir la línea de herencia, buscando entonces en su clase base, es decir, buscar `Personal_Universitario.datos`. Aquí *sí lo encontrará*

Por tanto `profe.datos` es en realidad `Personal_Universitario.datos`.

Lo mismo ocurre con `alumn.datos` y con `oficinista.datos`. Todos son el mismo diccionario `Personal_Universitario.datos`.

Puedes verificar esto con el operador `is` que te dice si dos objetos son en realidad el mismo (una sola copia en memoria):

```
>>> profe.datos is Personal_Universitario.datos
True
>>> alumn.datos is Personal_Universitario.datos
True
>>> oficinsta.datos is Personal_Universitario.datos
True
>>> profe.datos is alumn.datos and alumn.datos is oficinista.datos
True
```

Así que no es de extrañar el comportamiento que observas. Cada vez que en `Personal_Universitario.__init__()` asignas:

```
def __init__(self, datos=None):
        self.datos['id'] = datos['id']
        self.datos['nombre'] = datos['nombre']
        self.datos['email'] = datos['email']
```

Estás asignando al mismo (y único) diccionario. Al crear al oficinista, asignas ese diccionario. Al crear después al profe, vuelves a (re)asignar el mismo diccionario, y finalmente lo mismo con el alumno.

La solución es no declarar `datos` como un atributo de clase, sino como un atributo *de objeto*. Para ello no se escribe en la declaración de la clase, sino que directamente se crea ese atributo dentro del `__init__`.

Es decir, la clase debería ser así:

```
class Personal_Universitario:
    def __init__(self, datos=None):
        self.datos = {}    # <---- Aqui se crea, vacío
        self.datos['id'] = datos['id']   # Luego se le asignan valores
        self.datos['nombre'] = datos['nombre']
        self.datos['email'] = datos['email']

    def __str__(self):
        return '''
         Id: \t{}
         Nombre: {}
         Email: \t{}'''.format(self.datos['id'], self.datos['nombre'], self.datos['email'], end="")
```

La asignación `self.datos = {}` es la que crea ese atributo, pero lo crea en el objeto ya que para cuando esa función se ejecuta `self` será el `profe`, o el `oficinista` o el `alumn`. Cada uno de estos objetos tendrá su propio atributo `.datos`.

### Extra.

No veo especial ventaja en tener esos datos en un diccionario. Lo normal sería que esos datos fueran directamente atributos de cada objeto. Es decir, que los objetos tengan campos `profe.nombre`, `profe.id` o `profe.email`.

Con este enfoque tu código sería así:

```
class Personal_Universitario:
    def __init__(self, datos):
        self.id = datos['id']
        self.nombre = datos['nombre']
        self.email = datos['email']

    def __str__(self):
        return '''
         Id: \t{}
         Nombre: {}
         Email: \t{}'''.format(self.id, self.nombre, self.email, end="")


class Oficina(Personal_Universitario):

    def __init__(self, datos, puesto):
        super().__init__(datos)
        self.puesto = puesto

    def __str__(self):
        return super().__str__() + ''' 
      Puesto: {}'''.format(self.puesto)


class Profesor(Personal_Universitario):
    def __init__(self, datos, especializacion):
        super().__init__(datos)
        self.especializacion = especializacion

    def __str__(self):
        return super().__str__() + '''
         Especialización: {}'''.format(self.especializacion)


class Alumno(Personal_Universitario):
    def __init__(self, datos, creditos):
        super().__init__(datos)
        self.creditosAprobados = creditos

    def __str__(self):
        return super().__str__() + '''
         Creditos aprobados: {}'''.format(self.creditosAprobados)
```

Fíjate que he mantenido la *interfaz* de la clase, aunque he cambiado su implementación. Es decir, para crear el objeto aún hay que pasarle un diccionario `datos`, tal y como se hacía en tu código original:

```
persona1 = {'id': '50624002J', 'nombre': 'Alberto Torres', 'email': 'atb94ingmec@gmail.com'}
persona2 = {'id': '26598457P', 'nombre': 'Elena Garcia', 'email': 'elen98pol@gmail.com'}
persona3 = {'id': '45632589M', 'nombre': 'Jose Perez', 'email': 'Jose_95Per@gmail.com'}
oficinista = Oficina(persona3, 'Administrativo')
profe = Profesor(persona1, 'Matemáticas')
alumn = Alumno(persona2, 230)
```

Otra posibilidad es cambiar la interfaz de creación del objeto y hacer que los datos `id`, `nombre` y `email` sean parámetros separados en lugar de un diccionario `datos`. Es decir, los constructores serían:

```
class Personal_Universitario:
    def __init__(self, id, nombre, email):
        self.id = id
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.email = email

...

class Oficina(Personal_Universitario):
    def __init__(self, id, nombre, email, puesto):
        super().__init__(id, nombre, email)
        self.puesto = puesto

...

class Profesor(Personal_Universitario):
    def __init__(self, id, nombre, email, especializacion):
        super().__init__(id, nombre, email)
        self.especializacion = especializacion

# etc
```

Esto te obligará ahora a crearlos de otra forma:

```
profe = Profesor('50624002J', 'Alberto Torres', 'atb94ingmec@gmail.com', 'Matemáticas')
```

Aunque si quieres puedes aprovechar el diccionario que tenías en `persona1` y desempaquetarlo como parámetros, con el operador `**`, así:

```
oficinista = Oficina(**persona3, puesto='Administrativo')
profe = Profesor(**persona1, especializacion='Matemáticas')
alumn = Alumno(**persona2, creditos=230)
```

si bien encuentro esta sintaxis más confusa.

Comment: Esta respuesta que hice hace tiempo podría ayudar a entender de que habla Abulafia: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/426191/por-que-sucede-esto-con-modificacion-de-sublistas-en-python/426198#426198

Comment: Un explicación impresionante. Lo he entendido perfecto. Muchísimas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

#### Respuesta rápida

Estas definiendo de forma estática `datos` en la clase `Personal_Universitario`.

Si lo defines en el `__init__()` cada vez que se instancia se guarda los atributos de nuevo.

#### Código

```
from abc import ABC

class Personal_Universitario(ABC):

    def __init__(self, datos=None):
        self.datos = {}
        self.datos['id'] = datos['id']
        self.datos['nombre'] = datos['nombre']
        self.datos['email'] = datos['email']

    def __str__(self):
        return '''
         Id: \t{}
         Nombre: {}
         Email: \t{}'''.format(self.datos['id'], self.datos['nombre'], self.datos['email'], end="")

class Oficina(Personal_Universitario):

    def __init__(self, datos, puesto):
        super().__init__(datos)
        self.datos['puesto'] = puesto

    def __str__(self):
        return super().__str__() + ''' 
      Puesto: {}'''.format(self.datos['puesto'])

class Profesor(Personal_Universitario):

    def __init__(self, datos, especializacion):
        super().__init__(datos)
        self.datos['especializacion'] = especializacion

    def __str__(self):
        return super().__str__() + '''
         Especialización: {}'''.format(self.datos['especializacion'])

class Alumno(Personal_Universitario):

    def __init__(self, datos, creditos):
        super().__init__(datos)
        self.datos['creditosAprobados'] = creditos

    def __str__(self):
        return super().__str__() + '''
         Creditos aprobados: {}'''.format(self.datos['creditosAprobados'])


# Es mi información guardada en un diccionario, de diferentes personas.


persona1 = {'id': '50624002J', 'nombre': 'Alberto Torres', 'email': 'atb94ingmec@gmail.com'}
persona2 = {'id': '26598457P', 'nombre': 'Elena Garcia', 'email': 'elen98pol@gmail.com'}
persona3 = {'id': '45632589M', 'nombre': 'Jose Perez', 'email': 'Jose_95Per@gmail.com'}

# Creamos diferentes objetos de las distintas clases.

oficinista = Oficina(persona3, 'Administrativo')
profe = Profesor(persona1, 'Matemáticas')
alumn = Alumno(persona2, 230)
# Imprimimos la información del personal por pantalla.
print(oficinista)
print(profe)
print(alumn)
```

#### Comprobación

```
runfile('/home/gil/PycharmProjects/testing/test.py', wdir='/home/gil/PycharmProjects/testing')
         Id:    45632589M
         Nombre: Jose Perez
         Email:     Jose_95Per@gmail.com 
      Puesto: Administrativo
         Id:    50624002J
         Nombre: Alberto Torres
         Email:     atb94ingmec@gmail.com
         Especialización: Matemáticas
         Id:    26598457P
         Nombre: Elena Garcia
         Email:     elen98pol@gmail.com
         Creditos aprobados: 230
```

Comment: He comprendido mi error. Muchísimas gracias. Un saludo.