# Diccionario como atributo de una clase en Python, (¿asignar sus valores al crear un objeto?)

Tags: python, python-3.x, diccionarios, herencia

Soy principiante y estoy estudiando Herencia en Python.

Me han mandado un ejercicio que incluye diccionarios y me he hecho un lío, porque esto no lo hemos visto en clase y aunque he intentado resolverlo por mi cuenta, no funcionaba, así que al final copié el código de las clases de [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/431056/utilizar-un-diccionario-como-atributo-de-una-clase).

La segunda parte, la de guardar la información en el diccionario y crear objetos, estoy intentando resolverla de otra manera, donde pase los datos del diccionario directamente al crear el objeto, pero no sé si esto es posible. Me da error de sintaxis:

```
Input In [6]
    personal01 = Personal_Universitario(datos['id'] = 221, datos['nombre'] = "Ana", datos['email'] = "selene_ra86@hotmail.com")
                                        ^
SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?
```

Mi código es el siguiente:

## Completa el ejercicio aquí

```
class Personal_Universitario:
    datos = {
        'id': None,
        'nombre': None,
        'email': None
    }

    def __init__(self, datos=None):
        self.datos['id'] = datos['id']
        self.datos['nombre'] = datos['nombre']
        self.datos['email'] = datos['email']

    def __str__(self):
        return '''
         Id: \t{}
         Nombre: {}
         Email: \t{}'''.format(self.datos['id'], self.datos['nombre'], self.datos['email'], end="")


class Oficina(Personal_Universitario):

    def __init__(self, datos, puesto):
        super().__init__(datos)
        self.datos['puesto'] = puesto

    def __str__(self):
        return super().__str__() + ''' 
      Puesto: {}'''.format(self.datos['puesto'])


class Profesor(Personal_Universitario):
    def __init__(self, datos, especializacion):
        super().__init__(datos)
        self.datos['especializacion'] = especializacion

    def __str__(self):
        return super().__str__() + '''
         Especialización: {}'''.format(self.datos['especializacion'])


class Alumno(Personal_Universitario):
    def __init__(self, datos, creditos):
        super().__init__(datos)
        self.datos['creditosAprobados'] = creditos

    def __str__(self):
        return super().__str__() + '''
         Creditos aprobados: {}'''.format(self.datos['creditosAprobados'])

       
#Creamos los objetos y mostramos su información:

personal01 = Personal_Universitario(datos['id'] = 221, datos['nombre'] = "Ana", datos['email'] = "selene_ra86@hotmail.com")
print(personal01)
```

No me gustaría tener que copiar también esa parte del ejercicio, por eso me gustaría saber si hay una manera de hacerlo parecida a la que yo he planteado (u otra), o algo que yo no he entendido.

¡Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

El error en

```
personal01 = Personal_Universitario(datos['id'] = 221, datos['nombre'] = "Ana", datos['email'] = "selene_ra86@hotmail.com")
                                    ^
```

es que Python, a diferencia de C y derivados, no considera la asignación una *expresión* que produzca un valor, por lo que debes realizarlo en varios pasos:

```
datos['id'] = 221
datos['nombre'] = "Ana"
datos['email'] = "selene_ra86@hotmail.com"

personal01 = Personal_Universitario(datos)
                                    ^
```

También fijate que `Personal_Universitario` tiene un solo argumento, un diccionario desde donde se extrae el resto de la información. Tienes que pasar el diccionario completo, no cada item por separado.

Comment: Creo que ya lo pillo, gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Si te fijas en el constructor de tu clase:

```
class Personal_Universitario:
    # ...
    def __init__(self, datos=None):
        self.datos['id'] = datos['id']
        self.datos['nombre'] = datos['nombre']
        self.datos['email'] = datos['email']
```

verás que espera solo un parámetro (pues el `self` no cuenta). En tu intento le estás pasando varios. Además, el parámetro que le has de pasar no tiene por qué llamarse `datos`. De hecho, no necesita tener nombre alguno. Basta que sea un diccionario con los campos `id`, `nombre` y `email`, por lo que puedes invocar el constructor así:

```
personal01 = Personal_Universitario({"id": 221, "nombre": "Ana", "email": "selene_ra86@hotmail.com"})
```

O si lo prefieres, en vez de llaves y parejas clave-valor puedes usar un `dict()` con la sintaxis de parámetros nombre=valor, así:

```
personal01 = Personal_Universitario(dict(id=221, nombre="Ana", email="selene_ra86@hotmail.com"))
```

Ambas opciones son equivalentes. Es cuestión de preferencia personal qué sintaxis te gusta más. La primera sintaxis sería la única posible sin embargo si las claves del diccionario contuvieran espacios, comas, o en general no pudieran ser nombres de identificadores.

**NOTA ADICIONAL**. No necesitas "declarar" en la clase un atributo `datos` con valores iniciales None. Ese atributo de clase no es usado nunca, porque cada objeto tiene su propia copia del atributo `datos` (al que accedes a través de `self.datos` cuando estás en métodos del objeto, o a través de `objeto.datos` desde fuera del objeto. Nunca accederás a `Personal_Universitario.datos`).

Comment: Creo que ya lo he entendido, muchas gracias!!