# Tópicos sobre el método __init__

Tags: python

gente de stackoverflow.
El código mostrado lo cree específicamente para formular la pregunta.

Tengo entendido que el método **init** se utiliza, entre otras, para inicializar variables, para inicializar el objeto; también, que se ejecuta cada vez que se hace una instanciación.

En el código mostrado se aprecian 3 instanciaciones, [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]la pregunta es: por qué "listaprueba" no se inicializa a [] a partir de la segunda instanciación y preserva la o las listas precedentes (listalocal, mostrado en el resultado de la ejecución del código.); si se supone que una clase es como un patrón, un modelo a partir del cual crear objetos con identidad propia?

Comment: Pasa el código de imagen a texto, por favor. De esta manera la comunidad podrá copiar y ayudarte con cualquier consulta. Y aunque sea algo de observar solamente sin tener que modificar nada de nuestra parte en el código para ayudarte, tiene que ser en texto.

Comment: Gracias. Así lo haré en lo sucesivo.

Answer (score 0):

Bienvendio Pythonero c:

Primero que nada, Adrián tiene razon.

Segundo, tu error se debe a que todas las instancias comparten la misma lista. Esto se debe a que el valor default del argumento `listaprueba` es la misma lista, no una nueva. Observa lo que pasa en este código:

```
class SIN_lista_compartida:
    def __init__(Self, lista=None):
        # Creo una nueva lista si no se pasa ningún argumento.
        Self.lista = ([] if(lista is None) else lista)

    def append(Self, value):
        Self.lista.append(value)

class CON_lista_compartida:
    def __init__(Self, lista=[]):
        # Creo una nueva lista. Si no se pasa ninguna lista, le doy una lista compartida.
        Self.lista = lista

    def append(Self, value):
        Self.lista.append(value)


#### SIN lista compartida ####
l=SIN_lista_compartida()
l.append(None)

l2=SIN_lista_compartida()
l2.append("hola mundo")

print(l.lista)
print(l2.lista)
print()


#### CON lista compartida ####
l=CON_lista_compartida()
l.append(None)

l2=CON_lista_compartida()
l2.append("hola mundo")

print(l.lista)
print(l2.lista)
print()
```

La diferencia entre SIN_lista_compartida y CON_lista_compartida es que en el primero creo una nueva lista cada vez que se instancia la clase, en el segundo uso la lista default.

Espero haberme explicado bien, cualquier cosa puedes preguntarme. Este error es uno de los más comunes que cometen los desarrolladores en Python según esta pagina: https://www.toptal.com/python/codigo-buggy-python-los-10-errores-mas-comunes-que-cometen-los-desarrolladores-python

También te servirá leer [la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/426191/por-que-sucede-esto-con-modificacion-de-sublistas-en-python/426198#426198) que puse en otra pregunta que tuvo un problema similar al tuyo. Allí explico como funcionan los objetos en Python.

Comment: Cabe destacar que en las funciones en las que no se ha definido un método `__init__` ocurre exactamente lo mismo. Así que no tiene nada que ver con el modo en el que construyes el objeto, sino más bien con la forma en la que defines los valores de default.

Comment: Gracias; Dante, por la bienvenida y por tu respuesta. Leeré lo recomendado.

Answer (score 0):

El método `__init__` es un método constructor. Los métodos constructores existen en todo lo referente a programación orientada a objetos (OOP).

A partir de aquí puedes inicializar atributos de la clase. Efectivamente, cada vez que instancias una clase, se llama al método constructor de esta, es decir, al `__init__`.

Si por ejemplo ejecutamos el siguiente código:

```
class PruebaClase:
    def __init__(self, lista_testigo=[]):
        self.lista_testigo = lista_testigo

test = PruebaClase()

print(test.lista_testigo)
```

El resultado será el siguiente:

```
[]
```

Aunque al instanciar la clase no pases parámetros al método constructor, este está cogiendo por defecto la lista vacía que le has pasado como parámetro.

Sin embargo, si pasamos parámetros al instanciar la clase, ya que los puede recibir porque así lo defines en el método constructor, esta vez devolverá contenido la lista:

```
class PruebaClase:
    def __init__(self, lista_testigo=[]):
        self.lista_testigo = lista_testigo

test = PruebaClase(['A', 'B', 'C'])

print(test.lista_testigo)
```

¿Por qué sucede esto? Porque al hacer lo siguiente:

```
self.listaprueba.append(listalocal)
```

Estás modificando la lista en general, ya que es una referencia a la misma lista cada vez que lo llamas.

En lugar de hacer un append, podrías sumar al contenido de la propia lista los elementos de la nueva, por lo que podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
self.listaprueba + listalocal
```

Usando de ejemplo lo siguiente:

```
class PruebaClase():
    def __init__(self, lista_testigo=(), lista_prueba=[]):
        self.lista_testigo = lista_testigo
        self.lista_prueba = lista_prueba

    def llena_lista(self):
        listalocal = []
        for i in self.lista_testigo:
            listalocal.append(i)
        self.lista_prueba = self.lista_prueba + listalocal
    

lista_testigo = ['a','b','c']
miprueba = PruebaClase(lista_testigo)
miprueba.llena_lista()


lista_testigo = ['a','b','c']
miprueba1 = PruebaClase(lista_testigo)
miprueba1.llena_lista()

print(vars(miprueba))
print(vars(miprueba1))
```

Verás que ahora la `lista_prueba` no hace referencia a la misma lista:

```
{'lista_testigo': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'lista_prueba': ['a', 'b', 'c']}
{'lista_testigo': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'lista_prueba': ['a', 'b', 'c']}
```

Otra cosa:

- Las clases no llevan paréntesis como las funciones, por lo qué `Prueba_clase()` sería `Prueba_clase`.

Comment: Gracias, Adrian, por tu respuesta. Lo de los paréntesis viene de que aun soy novato en python y en oop. Aunque, veo que, en la herencia, se utilizan los paréntesis: class Mi_clase(Tk): por ejemplo

Comment: Sí, no te dará problemas en el código al colocar paréntesis aunque mejor evitarlos si no heredas. Gracias a ti, espero haber sido de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te ocurre no está relacionado con el método `__init__()` ni con la programación orientada a objetos, sino que es consecuencia de haber asignado a uno de los parámetros la lista vacía `[]` como valor por defecto.

Esto causa efectos secundarios inesperados como el que has observado. Para que esto quede más claro voy a poner el ejemplo más simple posible que ni siquiera usa OOP sino funciones normales.

```
def ampliar_lista(dato, lista=[]):
   lista.append(dato)
   return lista
```

Si esto lo llamas así:

```
l = [1, 2]
l2 = ampliar_lista(3, l)
```

produce el resultado esperado, la lista `l` resulta ampliada y pasa a valer `[1,2,3]` y ese mismo valor es asignado a `l2`, pues la función retorna la lista que acaba de ampliar. En ese punto `l` y `l2` son la misma lista (`l is l2` devolvería `True`).

Si lo llamas así:

```
l2 = ampliar_lista(5)
```

Entonces ya que no estamos pasando segundo parámetro, la `lista` dentro de la función tomará el valor `[]`, luego meterá el 5 y se retornará la lista resultante, con lo que `l2` valdrá `[5]`. Hasta aqui todo bien.

Y ahora viene la "sorpresa". Si tras haber ejecutado la línea anterior hacemos:

```
l3 = ampliar_lista(10)
```

cabría esperar que en `l3` hubiera `[10]`, por las mismas razones que hemos explicado en el caso anterior. Sin embargo encontrarás `l3` igual a `[5, 10]`. Y lo que es peor ¡`l2` también habrá cambiado de valor y será `[5,10]`! Compruébalo.

¿Por qué ocurre esto? Porque resulta que `l2` y `l3` son en realidad la misma lista, como puedes verificar si miras `l2 is l3` que te dirá `True`.

### Explicación

Al asignar el valor `[]` como valor por defecto para el parámetro `lista`, Python crea una lista vacía antes incluso de que la función se ejecute. El parámetro `lista` se referirá a esa lista vacía pre-creada. Digamos que la línea:

```
def ampliar_lista(dato, lista=[]):
```

es de algún modo equivalente a:

```
lista_pre_creada = []
def ampliar_lista(dato, lista=lista_pre_creada):
```

Así que cada vez que llames a `ampliar_lista()` omitiendo el segundo parámetro, se usará la `lista_pre_creada`, que siempre es la misma. Por esa razón esa lista va acumulando el 5 y el 10, porque es la misma en todas las llamadas que omitan el segundo parámetro.

### Solución

Como regla general **nunca pongas `[]` como valor por defecto para un parámetro** pues te encontrarás este tipo de problemas.

Se resuelve dando como valor por defecto `None` y detectando ese caso en el interior de la función:

```
def ampliar_lista(dato, lista=None):
    if lista is None:
       lista = []
    lista.append(dato)
    return lista
```

De este modo si omites el segundo parámetro, se crea una nueva lista vacía cada vez, dentro de la función.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta.