# Herencia de clases y listas - Python

Tags: python, lista, poo, herencia

primero he realizado un código funcional (mediante varias clases normales, todas con el mismo código dentro, COPY&PASTE). Luego, cuando he intentado trasladar este código a herencia de clases, entonces la lista no me la imprime correctamente... os mando el código de la herencia. También imágenes con los resultados que me aparecen.

Gracias

```
# Aquí arriba he definido la clase Familias para crear la ficha de cada cliente

class Casos:
casos = []

def __init__(self,name, casos =[]):
    self.casos = casos
    self.name = name
    print("Se creó la lista",self.name)

def agregar(self,fam):
    self.casos.append(fam)
    print("Se ha añadido a {} el cliente {}".format(self.name,fam.nombre))
    
def __str__(self):
    print("-->",self.name.upper())
    for fam in self.casos:
        print(fam)
    
class Psico(Casos):
    pass

class EdCachorro(Casos):
    pass
    
class EdBasico(Casos):
    pass
```

Código correcto, cuando cada clase tiene copy-paste con mismo código dentro
[image: Imagen del output esperado]

En cambio, cuando aplico herencia, me salen dentro de cada clase, todos los clientes que he creado, es decir, cuatro en cada clase.

MI DEDUCCIÓN: creo que lo que ocurre es, al crear las clases hijas, están heredando todos los objetos y métodos de las clases madre, por ende, también están heredando las fichas de clientes de las otras clases... no sé si el error va por ahí o me equivoco...

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Creo que el problema es el parámetro por defecto `casos=[]`. Cambialo por `casos=None` y dentro de `__init__()` haces `if casos is None: self.casos = []; else: self.casos = casos`. Además quita `casos=[]` de la clase, pues cada instancia tendrá su propia lista y la de la clase no se estaría usando para nada.

Comment: En [esta respuesta mia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/435990/7123) tienes más detalles sobre por qué se produce ese problema y la solución.

Comment: Estupendo!!! Millones de gracias por tu ayuda!!