# Poner un caracter en una lista doble en python

Tags: python, lista, python-3.7, random

estoy intentando poner un caracter al azar en uns lista bidimensional en python, dicha lista es cuadrada, de n x n. Por ello tengo el siguiente codigo

```
import random

n=3
cuadri = [[' '] * n] * n
i = random.randint(0,n-1)
j= random.randint(0,n-1)
cuadri[i][j]= 'a'
print(cuadri)
```

El problema es que no me pone un solo caracter, sino toda la columna con la letra a

Lo que me sale: `[[' ', 'a', ' '], [' ', 'a', ' '], [' ', 'a', ' ']]`

Lo que quiero: `[[' ', 'a', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ']]`

Supongo que esto es por la forma en que se construyó la lista, pero no estoy seguro de ello
Como puedo arreglarlo? Gracias!

Comment: `cuadri = [[' '] * n for i in range(n)]`

Comment: A otro usuario le pasó algo muy similar. Puedes mirar su pregunta y mi respuesta para solucionar tu problema: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/426191/158880