# Guardar dentro de una lista tipo ventana deslizante

Tags: python-3.7

Quiero hacer una ventana deslizante que vaya quitando el primer valor y agregando uno nuevo y ese resultado me lo guarde en trainY. Mi ventana de inicio es ventanaY, cuando aplico el for y le pongo print(ventanaY) veo que cambian los valores como los necesito pero al momento de guardarlo en trainY solo me los últimos 24 registros del ciclo for (como si hubiese recorrido todo el ciclo for y eso lo guarda para todos los registros).

Por otro lado, en train es que tengo mis datos con dependencia temporal que sirve para que mi ventana se actualice.

```
trainY = []
trainX = []
ventanaY = []

ventanaY = (df['demanda'].loc[25:48]).to_list()

for i in range(24,len(train),1):
  trainX.append(train['demanda'][i])
  trainY.append(ventanaY)
  ventanaY.pop(0) 
  ventanaY.append(train['demanda'][I])
```

df y train tienen el siguiente formato

```
df.head()

demanda
0   5488.0
1   5313.0
2   5106.0
3   4880.0
4   4707.0

train


demanda
24  5407.0
25  5046.0
26  4812.0
27  4788.0
28  4714.0
```

Comment: Prueba `trainY.append(ventanaY[:])` en la segunda linea del for

Comment: También, considera usar una [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) en vez de una lista para `ventanaY`. Es un tipo de lista al que le puedes dar una longitud máxima (24 en tu caso) y que se ocupa automáticamente de ir borrando los datos de un extremo cuando metes más de los que cabían por el otro.

Comment: Gracias !!, con ventana[:] guardó los datos como los necesitaba.

Answer (score 2):

El problema era que la línea:

```
  trainY.append(ventanaY)
```

añadía una **referencia** a la lista `vetanaY`, pero no una **copia** de esa lista que era lo que necesitabas. El siguiente código ayuda a comprender este problema:

```
lista =  [1]
otra_lista = [lista, lista, lista]
lista[0] = 100
print(otra_lista)
```

El resultado que saldrá es `[[100], [100], [100]]` porque `otra_lista` contiene tres referencias a la misma `lista` y no copias de ella.

Para guardar una copia debes usar `list()` alrededor de la lista que quieras copiar. Por ejemplo:

```
lista =  [1]
otra_lista = [list(lista), list(lista), list(lista)]
lista[0] = 100
print(otra_lista)
```

Ahora sale `[[1], [1], [1]]`, pues el `list(lista)` ha creado una nueva lista copiando los contenidos que `lista` tuviera *en ese momento* y por tanto ya no se ve afectado por los cambios que posteriormente hagas en `lista`.

En tu caso consistiría en poner `trainY.append(list(ventanaY))` o, como sugerí en un comentario, usar el slice `[:]` que también crea una copia de la lista completa.

En otro comentario te sugerí utilizar `deque()` para `ventanaY` ya que así no tienes que andar haciendo `pop(0)`, además de ser más rápido.

Seguidamente tienes un ejemplo completo y verificable de uso de `deque()` y del truco para copiar la lista (en este caso la deque). Para que el resultado no salga muy largo, he limitado los datos de ejemplo a solo 10, y el tamaño de la ventana a 5.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from collections import deque

# Generar datos de ejemplo
train = pd.DataFrame({'demanda': np.random.random(size=10)*1000+4000})
print(train)
```

Los datos generados son:

```
       demanda
0  4436.664432
1  4916.220119
2  4825.820841
3  4210.650083
4  4702.298902
5  4723.281204
6  4316.999071
7  4260.276835
8  4248.572219
9  4770.644248
```

Y el código de la ventana deslizante:

```
trainY = []
trainX = []
tam_ventana = 5

ventanaY = deque(maxlen=tam_ventana)
ventanaY.extend(train["demanda"][0:tam_ventana])

for i in range(len(train)):
  trainX.append(train['demanda'][i])
  trainY.append(list(ventanaY))
  ventanaY.append(train['demanda'][i])

print(trainY)
```

Produce el resultado:

```
[
[4436.664431878708, 4916.220118657259, 4825.8208405769055, 4210.650083361308, 4702.298901978815], 
[4916.220118657259, 4825.8208405769055, 4210.650083361308, 4702.298901978815, 4436.664431878708], 
[4825.8208405769055, 4210.650083361308, 4702.298901978815, 4436.664431878708, 4916.220118657259], 
[4210.650083361308, 4702.298901978815, 4436.664431878708, 4916.220118657259, 4825.8208405769055], 
[4702.298901978815, 4436.664431878708, 4916.220118657259, 4825.8208405769055, 4210.650083361308], 
[4436.664431878708, 4916.220118657259, 4825.8208405769055, 4210.650083361308, 4702.298901978815], 
[4916.220118657259, 4825.8208405769055, 4210.650083361308, 4702.298901978815, 4723.281203968541], 
[4825.8208405769055, 4210.650083361308, 4702.298901978815, 4723.281203968541, 4316.999071328533], 
[4210.650083361308, 4702.298901978815, 4723.281203968541, 4316.999071328533, 4260.2768351444365], 
[4702.298901978815, 4723.281203968541, 4316.999071328533, 4260.2768351444365, 4248.572218958103]
]
```

De todas fomas veo todo este código demasiado "artesanal". Dependiendo de lo que pretendas hacer con los datos de la ventana, probablemente te interese investigar los métodos de pandas para [rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html)

Comment: Encuentro preferible `lista.copy()` a `list(lista)`, pues "copy()" es mono tarea y expresa mejor la intención. Al ver `list(lista)` en un programa pienso que el programador simplemente quiere asegurarse de contar con una lista; no se me ocurría que está sacando una copia. Otros probablemente tampoco detectarían la trampa en donde tantos caen (referencia vs copia).

Comment: Relacionado: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/426198/158880