# Python asignar listas a variables

Tags: python, array, variables

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = a
b[1] = 1000
    
print(a)
print(b)
```

Imprime

```
[1, 1000, 3]
[1, 1000, 3]
```

No entiendo por qué `a[1] = 1000`, esperaba que `a[1] = 2`

Comment: This is the spanish site of StackOverflow, please translate your ask

Comment: instead of been scared I recommend you to read [ask] and translate your question into spanish

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo generar dos nuevas cadenas sin reemplazar las originales?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/425810/c%c3%b3mo-generar-dos-nuevas-cadenas-sin-reemplazar-las-originales)

Answer (score 6):

En python la asignación del estilo `a=b` asigna en realidad una *referencia*.

Esto quiere decir que a partir de `a=b`, `a` se refiere al mismo *objeto subyacente* (en tu caso una lista) a la que se refería `b`. Por tanto tanto si haces `a[1]` como `b[1]` estás accediendo al mismo lugar.

Es por eso que Python incluye el operador de comparación `is` que sirve para saber si dos variables se refieren o no al mismo objeto subyacente. Si en tu ejemplo hicieras `print(a is b)` verías que te devuelve `True`, lo que significa que efectivamente se refieren al mismo objeto.

Si lo que quieres es que `a` sea una **copia** de `b` (y no meramente una referencia que apunta al mismo objeto), debes copiarlo explícitamente. Esto puedes hacerlo así:

```
a = b.copy()
```

Si después de esto haces `print(a is b)` verás que ahora te dirá `False`. Los objetos (listas) a que se refieren `a` y `b` son dos objetos independientes. A pesar de que inicialmente contengan los mismos datos porque los has copiado (`a==b` te dirá `True` porque compara los valores en vez de las referencias).

Si modficas ahora `a[1]` no afectarás a `b`.

### Notas

En lugar de `a = b.copy()` también suele verse el truco `a = b[:]`. Este truco funciona porque el operador de rebanada (o *slice*) siempre copia los datos y devuelve una copia, en lugar de referencias a los datos originales, y porque al omitir el índice de inicio y fin de la rebanada, se copiará la lista completa.

Si la lista `b` contuviera sub-listas, la operación de copia (tanto `b.copy()` como `b[:]`) **no copian las sublistas**, sino sólo las referencias a esas sublistas.

Por ejemplo considera `b = [[0,1], [2,3], [4,5]]`

Si hacemos `a = b` sólo se copia una referencia a la lista "exterior", por lo que un intento de modificar `a[1]`, modificará también `b[1]` como ya hemos visto.

Gráficamente la situación es esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ves, tanto `a` como `b` "apuntan" a la misma lista, pero esta lista está a su vez compuesta de referencias (o "apuntadores") a otras sublistas.

Si en cambio realizas la copia por ejemplo así:

```
a = b.copy()
```

Entonces se creará una lista nueva para `a`, que contendrá referencias a sublistas, pero estas referencias serán *a las mismas sublistas* que son referenciadas desde la lista `b`. Gráficamente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aunque `a` ya no apunta a la misma lista que `b` (y por tanto `a is b` será `False`), sin embargo `a[1]` se refiere a la misma sublista que se refiere `b[1]`, por lo que si haces `a[1][0] = 1000` se llegaría a esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y por tanto al imprimir tanto `a` como `b` obtendrías:

```
[[0,1], [1000,3], [4,5]]
```

Para evitar esto tendrías que hacer una *copia profunda*, en la que se desciende recursivamente todos los niveles de sublistas que contenga la lista y se va obteniendo una copia separada de cada una:

```
import copy

a = copy.deepcopy(b)
```

Ahora la situación sería esta otra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la que cualquier modificación en `a` o sus sub-listas no afectará a `b`.

**Nota**. Los gráficos mostrados se han obtenido con ayuda de la web http://pythontutor.com que es muy útil para entender este tipo de cosas y te permite crear tus propios experimentos y ver cómo es la estructura de datos subyacente.

Answer (score 2):

Python, y algunos otros lenguajes, asignan la referencia de las estructuras de datos (listas, tuplas, diccionarios) a las variables. Eso quiere decir que `a` y `b` en realidad no valen el arreglo, si no que son iguales a la referencia en memoria donde está guardada la estructura.

Te voy a ilustrar un caso curioso:

```
def f1(data):
    data.append(3)
    return data
    
a = [1, 2]
b = f1(a)
print(a) # [1, 2, 3]
print(b) # [1, 2, 3]
```

Es más, este otro caso es aún más curioso:

```
def f1(data):
    data.append(3)
    
a = [1, 2]
b = f1(a) # La funcion no tiene return, por lo que debería devolver None
print(b) # None
print(a) # [1, 2, 3] # Pensarías que, WTF? pero es así
```

Para asignar una copia de una estructura en otra variable, puedes usar [copy() o slicing](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-copy-an-object-in-python), `[:]`

```
a = [1, 2]
b = a[:] # Copia de a en una nueva referencia

b.append(6)
print(a) # [1, 2]
print(b) # [1, 2, 6]
```

Comment: Tambien puedes usar el metodo .copy() para copiar la lista, como dijo @Abulafia en su respuesta