# ¿Por qué al guardar un objeto en una lista, cambia la lista si cambia el objeto?

Tags: python

Creo que no estoy entendiendo algo con las listas en Python.
Tengo la función "agregar" en la clase Controlador, la misma guarda el estado del objeto "registro" en la "pila" antes de agregar la persona al registro, sin embargo al correr la función "controlador.agregar()",guarda el objeto persona en la lista del registro y en la pila también.

Ejemplo:

controlador.agregar(Persona('Carlos', 29)). el comportamiento esperado es que controlador.pila.lista esté vacía y controlador.registro.lista tenga el objeto "Persona", pero no es así.

Aquí el código.

```
class Persona():
    def __init__(self, nombre, edad):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.edad = edad

class Registro():
    def __init__(self):
        self.lista =[]

    def agregar(self, persona):
        self.lista.append(persona)


class Pila():
    def __init__(self):
        self.lista = []

    def apilar(self, objeto):
        self.lista.append(objeto)

    def desapilar(self):
        if len(self.lista) != 0:
            return self.lista.pop()
    
    def vacio(self):
        return self.lista == []

class Controlador():
    def __init__(self):
        self.registro = Registro()
        self.pila = Pila()

    def agregar(self, persona):
        self.pila.apilar(self.registro)
        self.registro.agregar(persona)

    def deshacer(self):
        objeto = self.pila.desapilar()
        if objeto.__class__.__name__ == self.registro.__class__.__name__:
            self.registro = objeto


controlador = Controlador()
```

Comment: Cuando agregas un objeto a lista, **no estás haciendo una copia**. Simplemente anotadas que ahí va el objeto en cuestión. Puedes poner el mismo objeto en múltiples contenedores y sólo existirá una copia de él, referenciada desde múltiples ubicaciones ( o con "nombres diferentes" si lo quieres ver así).

Comment: Mira [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/426393/80870) y sus respuestas.

Comment: Entonces según entiendo, la única forma de obtener el resultado que quiero es haciendo una copia del objeto en la pila mientras el objeto original queda en "registro". ¿debería usar el modulo "copy"?

Comment: si quieres puedes usar el módulo `copy` como dices pero recuerda que debes implementar los métodos necesarios en tus clases