# Problema al asignar valor a lista

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo el siguiente código

```
def InLi(le):
    a = [0] * (le + 1)
    return a

W=P=L=A=B=K= InLi(2)

W[1] = 2
P[1] = 2
L[1] = 4
A[1] = 2
B[1] = 2
K[1] = 1

W[2] = 2
P[2] = 2
L[2] = 4
A[2] = 2
B[2] = 2
K[2] = 1
```

Pero los indexs no adoptan el valor que les doy, cuando ejecuto:

```
print(W)
print(P)
print(L)
print(A)
print(B)
print(K)
```

Al final, la salida es:

```
[0, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 1]
```

¿Por qué pasa esto? Aclaro que mi objetivo principal es crear esas listas "vacias"(Con ceros) pero con determinada longitud de valores. Y después rellenar ciertas posiciones con el código descrito.

Comment: Ya respondieron, pero la explicación es que en Python y otros lenguajes en realidad no se asignan arreglos (listas, tuplas, etc) a variables, se asigna la referencia. Entonces el valor W=P=L=A=B=K es igual a la misma referencia. Lo que hagas en una, se replica a todas. Ver https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/426403/80870

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo generar dos nuevas cadenas sin reemplazar las originales?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/425810/c%c3%b3mo-generar-dos-nuevas-cadenas-sin-reemplazar-las-originales)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que todas las variables están tomando el valor de *K*, la solución sería ejecutar la función `InLi` en todas las variables por separado

```
K=InLi(2)
B=InLi(2)
A=InLi(2)
L=InLi(2)
P=InLi(2)
W=InLi(2)
```

Entonces, al hacer lo siguiente

```
W[1] = 2
P[1] = 2
L[1] = 4
A[1] = 2
B[1] = 2
K[1] = 1

W[2] = 2
P[2] = 2
L[2] = 4
A[2] = 2
B[2] = 2
K[2] = 1
print(W)
print(P)
print(L)
print(A)
print(B)
print(K)
```

La salida será

```
[0, 2, 2]
[0, 2, 2]
[0, 4, 4]
[0, 2, 2]
[0, 2, 2]
[0, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Lo que más quería era evitar eso, no se, siento que es poco optimo, pero bueno, será esa la solución ¡Gracias!